# Android - How to change Default Loading Screen(Screenshot)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

when i run Unity3D use android grandle build. It show up with loading screen like below screenshot. How can i remove this screen or change this with black screen?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can disable unity logo if you have pro license

Comment: I know it, but this is not Unity Logo, it's icon of App, after loading this, this will load to Unity Activity contain Logo